# DHMS to concatenate date and time to datetime causes the first date to be 1/1/1960

Tags: function, datetime, sas, time-series, concatenation

I am creating a time series of intraday (1 minute interval) time series. I have the variables date YYYYMMDD and time HH:MM:SS and would like to create the datetime YYYYMMDDTHH:MM:SS (or whatever format is not too important).

When looking at the output (just sample dates):

```
Date        Time                  Datetime
20000101    9:30:00               1960-01-01T09:30:00
20000101    9:31:00               2000-01-01T09:31:00
.
.
.
20000102    9:30:00               1960-01-01T09:30:00
20000102    9:31:00               2000-01-02T09:31:00
```

SO whenever time is 9:30:00 the concatenation via dhms(date, 0, 0, time) gives me the wrong value.

My code actually picks stock prices in certain interval from higher frequency data:

```
data xtemp2; 
 set _v_&tables; 
 by symbol date time; 
 format datetime e8601dt. itime rtime time12.; 
 if first.symbol = 1 or first.date = 1 then do; 

    /* Initialize time and price when new symbol or date starts; */

    rtime = time; 
    iprice = bid; 
    oprice = ofr; 
    itime = &start_time; 
    datetime = time;
 end; 

 if time >= itime then do;
       output;
       itime = itime + &interval_seconds; 
       do while(time >= itime);
           output; 
           itime = itime + &interval_seconds; 
       end; 
end; 
rtime = time; 
iprice = bid; 
oprice = ofr; 
datetime = dhms(date, 0,0,itime);
retain itime datetime iprice oprice;                                            
run;
```

Is it something in my code? because looking at the distinct date and time variable shows the correct date.

I wanted to combine these because I have a time series for each stock and would like to match merge them which - if I understand correctly - requires one unique id that could be my datetime variable.

Comment: Your date values look incorrect, is this a typo or your actual values?

Comment: Please apologize of course it's 20000101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with this piece of conditional logic:

`if first.symbol = 1 or first.date = 1 then do;`

This means that the first instance of those by groups will execute `datetime = time;` instead of `datetime = dhms(date, 0,0,itime);` (presuming `time >= itime` is true).

I suggest replacing `datetime = time;` with `datetime = dhms(date, 0,0,itime);` in the first instance.

Comment: Thanks, Allan, that was it! I should have initialized differently!